# Whats the difference in setting up Database in Liferay among these approaches?

Tags: liferay-6

I am using liferay 6 for my Application .
I am trying to use Mysql with Liferay here .

please tell me whats the diference between these two approaches ??

**First Approach :**

step-1   modify `portal-ext.properties`

```
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
```

step-2 modify $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

```
<Context…> <Resource name=”jdbc/LiferayPool” auth=”Container” type=”javax.sql.DataSource” driverClassName=”com.mysql.jdbc.Driver” url=”jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8″ username=”root” password=”root” maxActive=”100″ maxIdle=”30″ maxWait=”10000″ /> </Context>
```

**Second Approach  :**

modify `portal-ext.properties`

```
 #
    # MySQL
    #
    jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
    jdbc.default.username=root
    jdbc.default.password=root
```

Comment: The first one uses the DataSource configured in your Tomcat, the second one uses the connection pool built into Lifery (don't know what they are using)

Comment: Thanks , whats the best approach to choose among these when going to production ?